# Removing an ng-repeat without leaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, memory-leaks

I appear to have a memory leak in an Angular based app I've been looking at and I've reduced it to this test case: http://plnkr.co/edit/JIt8PrV28lKnlSx8I8xP?p=preview .

Basically it comes down to the fact that I don't know how to cleanly remove the ng-repeat from the document. If I use `jQuery().remove()` the table is gone from the document, but cached listeners (`$watchCollectionAction()` for example) cause a leak.

I've got a `$scope.$destroy()` call where I want to clean up in the example at the moment, but that isn't the answer...

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you call first $destroy() and then remove()

Comment: I have tried that. What is surprising me is that the `$destroy()` call doesn't appear to remove the listeners that Angular appears to be adding.

Comment: given the example it is not quite clear to me what you want to remove? All the rows created by the "<tr ng-repeat" directive? Then you could just set showCase.persons to an empty array.

Comment: I've added `persons.splice( 0, persons.length );` (the URL above has been updated with this) but that doesn't empty the HTML. All I really want to do is eliminate the items from the DOM without any memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The plunkr example works if the timeout function is

```
setTimeout( function () {
    vm.persons = [];
    $scope.$apply();
}, 1000 );
```

The `$apply` is needed since you made a change from outside the Angular machinery (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. however, it doesn't appear to be a clean remove. There are still items in the listener cache that are leaking. I've made an updated plunk here: http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/gWEZhKZaqVX52i0QAEFX/ . This is a screenshot showing the retained cache: http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2015-07-10_at_16.16.40-XIeofB0C.png

Comment: I don't use Chrome or know how to interpret its heap analysis so I can't help here. But it would be a huge bug if these objects are really leaking, so you might consider to post your problem on a Angular dev list.